# DeCaptcher API for ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am working with rails 3.2 and want to request some services from http://api.de-captcher.com/ using its api.

I googled a lot but I didn't get any tutorial or guide to do this with ruby on rails.

Can anyone please help me to find some good tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to defeat the purpose of a CAPTCHA?

Comment: I am getting some info from some site using API, where I have to enter captcha. So, it needs to call de-captcher's api to get text for that captcha

Comment: I've never seen an API with a CAPTCHA. Care to mention what API this is? APIs are for software, CAPTCHA is for humans. Most likely you would be violating the Terms of Service of the site.

Comment: Please read the question... I mentioned the API

Comment: No, you didn't mention where you would be "getting some info from some site using API where I have to enter captcha".

Comment: Thanks... got the solution... I used cookies while http get and post requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer!

Just create GET and POST requests with cookies. Keep in mind that both the requests (GET and POST) should be in same session